# Infopath 2007 browser form code not working in MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have a Sharepoint 2007 (MOSS) Server and i want to publish an InfoPath form with managed code to it.

I have already published alot of InfoPath forms in the past, and everything is working fine.

The only problem is, that the code that i put in the Form, is not running in the sharepoint site, but only in the infopath application preview.

Any ideas?

The code is a simple one that change the DataSource location and adds a filter to it like here: http://edgedev.blogspot.com/2008/09/bending-infopath-and-sharepoint-to-your.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you published the form to a document library. I know that your infopath codes runs only on "Form Library" document libraries.

Try it,

P.S.: And you must publish it as "administration approved form"